# How do I stop a while loop when a key is pressed with Autokey?

Tags: python, autokey

I'm trying to write a small script with **Autokey** (not regular Python) on Linux Mint which presses a single key and stops after I press another specific key but I can't get it to stop the loop after I press this specific key.

I got the loop working but I can't make it stop.

```py
import time
a = True
b = keyboard.press_key('s')
keyboard.release_key('s')
while a:
    keyboard.send_key("a", repeat=5)
    time.sleep(2)
    if b:
        break
```

So this outputs the letter "a" indefinitely and after I press "s" it doesn't stop and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

I read about the while function and break but all the examples I found were with a loop stopping after it reached a certain number and these examples with numbers are different than what I try to achieve with this kind of script so I hope someone can help me to figure this out.

Comment: Hi, can you provide your full code with all imports and whatnot?

Comment: This is the full code, I wrote this to practice

Comment: `b` never changes.

Comment: @minionlou There is no way this is the full code. When I paste this into my IDE and run it, I get `NameError: name 'keyboard' is not defined`. Which means at the bare minimum you are missing an import statement.

Comment: This code doesn't work then. It says that `keyboard is not defined` when run.

Comment: It's running for me, I wrote this inside of Autokey not inside python or the terminal. Maybe that's why it's not working for you?

Comment: To all: This is the documentation of the `Keyboard` class in AutoKey. https://autokey.github.io/index.html

Comment: The AutoKey Keyboard class is for sending keyboard events. It doesn't look like it's for detecting the user typing.

Comment: It has `keyboard.wait_for_keypress()`, but it looks like it blocks until the user types something, so it won't be useful here.

Comment: @Barmar ```import keyboard``` works fine for this.

Comment: I can't test this on my machine (WSL) but you might be able to use the builtin `threading` library to run `keyboard.wait_for_keypress('s')` on its own thread and when it's done you could use some form of inter-thread communication to change the condition of your while loop to false thus stopping the sending of keypresses.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use the keyboard module for this, because `press_key` is used to "press" the keys not to detect.

If you haven't already installed keyboard you can do it by going to cmd,
`pip install keyboard`

after that you can add the code in python as follows, pressing "q" will print "a" 5 times and pressing "s" will stop the program.

```
import keyboard
while True: 
   if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # pressing q will print a 5 times
      for i in range(5):
         print("a")
      break  
   elif keyboard.is_pressed('s'): # pressing s will stop the program
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a key is pressed with [evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

Check your InputDevice by looking at `python -m evdev.evtest`

Then to check if the `s` key is pressed :

```
import evdev
from evdev import ecodes as e

device = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event7')

if e.KEY_S in device.active_keys():
    do_something()
```

Answer (score -2):

At first glance your problem is that you never update the value of b and it is only assigned before the loop. You should probably try something like this:

```py
import time
a = True
keyboard.release_key('s')
while a:
    keyboard.send_key("a", repeat=5)
    b = keyboard.press_key('s')
    time.sleep(2)
    if b:
        break
```

I don't know how "b = keyboard.press_key('s')" affects the code, if it stops it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question. `keyboard.press_key` is documented as pressing a key on the keyboard and not checking if it is pressed or not. Please use comments for things that are not solutions.